# SQLite String start with first 6 letters in alphabet table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select the name strings that the first character to be on of A to F or a to f, here is my select clause, but I got noting returned.

```
SELECT name FROM pet WHERE lower(name) LIKE '[A-Fa-f]%';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `GLOB` operator here:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM pet
WHERE name GLOB '[A-Fa-f]*';
```

Comment: I _think_ op wants the first character to be on of A to F. ("first 6 letters".)

Comment: @jarlh I think you're right.  I have Stack dyslexia, and sometimes misinterpret things.

Comment: Unclear questions tend to get answers to somewhat different problems.

Comment: Pardon my question is not clear, I updated the question as @jarlh mentioned above

Comment: @SLN My current answer should meet your requirements.  Use `GLOB`.